# Doxygen gives error when producing RTF output

Tags: c#, doxygen

I am running Doxygen 1.8.5 on a C# project and I get the below errors when processing.  I've searched the web for an answer but have not found much of anything.  I'd switch to HTML or some other output but RTF is needed to support the current project.  Inherited this from someone that left with no documentation from them.

```
error: problems opening rtf file namespaces.rtf for reading
error: An error occurred during post-processing the RTF files!
*** Doxygen has finished
```

I don't see "namespaces.rtf" in the output dir but I do see files of the form "namespace_xyz.rtf".

Thanks for any help!,
CF

Comment: Clearly not good, but how can one reproduce this?

Comment: Got the same error. It seems it appears whenever "SHOW_NAMESPACES" is not checked (checking it resolved the error).

Comment: I had a similar problem and eventually found it was because I had the directive `\page files`. (For me it was `problems opening rtf file files.rtf` I was unsuccessfully trying to customize the top section of the files page.  I had tried this because it worked for the todo page)